# Angular js memory leak and website hang issue

Tags: angularjs, performance

How to overcome this issue as website hangs and become unresponsive within 5 min

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question? Such as which website and any other errors/circumstances in which this is happening

Comment: Overlook your code (#cycles / data loops / ....) :) - or ask specific advice if you provide some detailed information / visible codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Open the site with Chrome and open the Developer tools and start exploring!
Check the network tab and try CPU profiling, your question lacks details. Upload an example...

Watch this more specific video to your question:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4Uvk5zxrhM

Answer (score 0):

Install the Chrome plugin 'Batarang' to profile the performance of your AngularJS project. It will give you some insight about the digest cycles / performance. Such information in combination with some code can point to the cause of your problem.

[Google Chrome plugin Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)